# How to demonstrate the sequence $y_{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1} + \frac23 y_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, alternative-proof, convolution

**Context**

While answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3431621/convergence-of-a-sequence-y-k-defined-by-recurrence-relation/3431641#3431641) I noticed that the procedure used there could be extended to show that any sequence of the form
$$y_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_{n-k}x_k, \ \ n=0,1,2\dots\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
is null if the series $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely and $(x_n)$ is a null sequence.

I wanted to create some examples, as variations of the one proposed in the above mentioned question, and came up with, e.g.,

$$y_{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1} + \frac23 \cdot y_n, \ \ n=0,1,2,\dots,\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$
and *arbitrary* $y_0\neq 0$.

With the change of variable $z_n = y_n -3$ you can then write
$$z_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-k}x_k,$$
with
$$
x_n=
\begin{cases}
z_0 & (x=0)\\
-\frac{1}{n+1} & (n>0),
\end{cases}
$$
that is exactly the form \eqref{eq1}, and it satisfies the hypotheses. So the sequence $(z_n)$ is null and $(y_n)$ converges to $3$, independently of the intial value $y_0$.

**Question**

I think from \eqref{eq2} the convergence to $3$ is sort of *obvious*, but I was not able to come up with a less "convoluted" way to show it. Could you provide me with an alternative proof of the convergence of $(y_n)$?

Comment: (1) is a special case of [$A = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ and $b_n \to B$ implies $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k} \to AB$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1823486/42969) (which turned out to be equivalent to Merten's theorem about the Cauchy product).

Comment: Stolz's theorem also works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
y_{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1} + \frac23 \cdot y_n \tag{2}
$$
implies that the sequence is *bounded:*
$$
|y_n| \le \max(3, |y_0|)
$$
is easily shown with induction. Therefore both
$$
I = \liminf_{n\to \infty} y_n \, , \,
S = \limsup_{n\to \infty} y_n
$$ are finite, and then $(2)$ implies that
$$
 I = 1 + \frac 23 I \, , \, S = 1 + \frac 23 S
$$
so that $I=S= 3$.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the iteration of the form $z_{n+1} = a+\frac{2}{3}z_n$ where $a$ is constant. Then subtracting $3a$ you get $z_{n+1}-3a = \frac{2}{3}(z_n-3a)$. This means that $z_{n}-3a$ is geometric and it always converges to $0$ regardless of the initial value $z_0$. This means that $z_n\to 3a$.

Now it is enough to see that for some $\varepsilon >0$ eventually you have $n/(n+1)>1-\varepsilon$ if $n \geq n_0$. Therefore, you consider the recurrence of the form $z_{n+1} = 1-\varepsilon + \frac{2}{3}z_n$ and $w_{n+1} = 1+\frac{2}{3}w_n$ for $n \geq n_0$ and $z_{n_0}=w_{n_0}=y_{n_0}$ then
$ z_n\leq y_n \leq w_n$ for every $n$. The initial paragraph above says that

$$ 3-3\varepsilon \leq \liminf_{n\to \infty} y_n \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} y_n \leq 3 $$

Now it is enough to take $\varepsilon \to 0$ to get that $\lim_{n\to \infty } y_n = 3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z_n = y_n - 3$. We have
$z_{n+1} = \frac23 z_n - \frac{1}{n+1}.$

We use Mathematical Induction to prove
that $|z_n| \le \frac{3|z_0| + 12}{n+1}$ for all $n \ge 2$.

When $n = 2$, true.

Assume that it is true for $n$ ($n\ge 2$).

For $n+1$, we have
$$|z_{n+1}| \le \frac23|z_n| + \frac{1}{n+1}
\le \frac23 \cdot \frac{3|z_0| + 12}{n+1} + \frac{1}{n+1} \le \frac{3|z_0| + 12}{n+2}$$
where we use
$$\frac{3|z_0| + 12}{n+2} - \frac23 \cdot \frac{3|z_0| + 12}{n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{(n-1)|z_0| + 3(n-2)}{(n+1)(n+2)} \ge 0.$$

We are done.